# Compilter Directives - Suggestion - Run code in Debug mode only

Tags: c#, performance, compiler-directives

I need to Log messages only when application is running in debug mode. I have found 2 ways:

**First**: Need to write 3 lines everywhere when logging is needed. But, Logger statement is disabled at compile time only which is exactly I need. Logger.Log will not be executed at all.

```
#if DEV_ENV
        Logger.Log("Application started !"); // This line is grayed. Perfect !
#endif

public static void Log(string message)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(message);
}
```

**Second**: Very neat. Only one line of code wherever logging is required. Not sure, whether Logger.Log statement is executed or not. **If function call is removed at compile time only (same as first approach. But, now sure as line of code is not greyed out), I want to go with this.**

```
Logger.Log("Application started !"); // This line is not grayed out. But, function is not called. So, confused whether its removed at compile time.

[Conditional("DEV_ENV")]
public static void Log(string message)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(message);
}
```

**I am concerned about the performance differences.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MSDN](http://www.msdn.com) page for the [ConditionalAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx):

> Applying ConditionalAttribute to a
>   method indicates to compilers that **a
>   call to the method should not be
>   compiled** into Microsoft intermediate
>   language (MSIL) unless the conditional
>   compilation symbol that is associated
>   with ConditionalAttribute is defined.

So, as it says, the method call is removed at compile time, same as the `#if`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your compile settings, you could use:

```
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
   Logger.Log("Application started !");
```

or,

```
#if DEBUG
    Logger.Log("Application started !"); 
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

As George points out, the method call will not be compiled if the Conditional attribute is applied. This also means (as with removing the code directly using `#If DEV_ENV`) that any side effects included in the method call will also not occur - as always, the warning about having side effects in logging code are well founded:

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    int i = 92;
    Log(string.Format("{0} became {1}", i++, i));
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

[Conditional("SKIP")]
private static void Log(string msg)
{
    Console.WriteLine(msg);
}
```

If `SKIP` is not defined, this code prints out `92`. If `SKIP` is defined, it prints `92 became 93` and `93`.

Comment: Thank you. Question: Will Log(string.Format("{0} became {1}", i++, i)); statement be compiled in assembly?